# Metric tensor in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: cylindrical-coordinates

In a system of curvilinear coordinates, $(q^1,q^2,q^3)$, basis vector can be derived by differentiating a generic position $M(q^1,q^2,q^3)$ with respect to the coordinates, ie $$\mathbf{e}_i=\frac{\partial M}{\partial q^i}$$ and the expression of the metric tensor is $$g_{ik}=\mathbf{e}_i\cdot \mathbf{e}_k$$ Can I find the expression of this metric tensor in a system of cylindrical coordinates without using any other system of coordinates?

Comment: If you know $M(q)$ when $q$ are cylindrical coordinates, sure. As it stands, your question is pretty vague.

Comment: Well, if I use cylindrical coordinates, I know that $M(r,\theta,z)$ for instance. What else can I do?

Comment: Oh, I see. Your point is that we would need the $xyz$-coordinates in order to write $M(r,\theta,z) = (r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,z)$.  When you write $\mathbf e_i\cdot\mathbf e_k$, you are presuming that everything lives in some space where I know how to compute a dot product, and so I need $M$ to give me coordinates in that space.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes exactly! for the first part of your answer. So, the second part says that we cannot avoid the use of $M(r,θ,z)=(r\cos θ,r\sin θ,z)$?

Comment: You can define an abstract Riemannian metric in the coordinate system, but if you're thinking of the metric as coming from a fixed space in which your manifold sits, then you need to know how it does so.

Comment: @TedShifrin You might want to provide an answer that I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what you mean by the dot product in your defining equation for $g_{ik}$. If you are defining an abstract Riemannian metric, then your manifold is an abstract thing. But, ordinarily, when you refer to cylindrical coordinates, you're thinking of $\Bbb R^3$ as your ambient space and you're using "$\cdot$" to represent the dot product on $\Bbb R^3$. In that case, you're going to need to compute $\mathbf e_i$ as vectors in $\Bbb R^3$, and for that you'll need specific coordinates in $\Bbb R^3$ for $M(r,\theta,z)$.